# What is preferable approach to merge changes from develop into master branch?

Tags: git

Master is main branch and is locked from direct merge request.

Develop is branched off master.

Feature1 is branched off Develop branch.

I can pull the code from Feature1 branch to my local GIT and make changes, and commit the code locally.

Now I have two options to integrate changes to develop branch:

1. To bring the code changes from feature1 into develop we can either do merge squash or rebase feature1 into develop locally and then push develop to the server. Merge squash doesn't retain previous feature commit histories. Where as rebase will keep the history.
2. The other way, instead of merging code locally from feature1 into develop, we can push the feature 1 branch to the server and then raise a pull request on the server to merge the code from feature1 branch to develop branch. Here will the commit history from feature1 get stored or ignored when merging to develop branch?

Which is preferable approach?

Comment: You should always pull request into master, master should always be locked. Albeit this question is primarily opinion-based

Comment: Ok I will update the question

Comment: I'll go with option 2, creating PR to merge from your feature1 branch to develop, I'm also making an assumption that your PR has to be approved and undergoes code review, before you can merge. I believe the PR history which contains your changes is preserved. I'm speaking from my experience and preference, Also, I'm using BitBucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not the only one working on `feature1`, a PR to merge it to `develop` is preferable.
A rebase would involve a force push, making your colleague having to reset their own `feature1` branch.

To keep the history of `feature1`, consider a regular merge when accepting the PR, not a "[squash and merge](https://help.github.com/en/articles/merging-a-pull-request#merging-a-pull-request-on-github)".

For `develop` to `master`, you are not the only one integrating features, so a PR is recommended, to merge (not rebase) `develop`.

Comment: When I do merge from feature to develop branch, and delete the feature branch, then I loose all commit history from develop branch for that feature and it shows one history record for that merge. Is there any way i can keep the history on the develop branch, is rebase a solution?

Comment: @variable You do keep the history, in the second parent of your merge commit.

Comment: History will be kept only when I do normal merge right? And not when I do merge squash

Comment: @variable Yes. Considering you dod not mention squashing, I assumed a regular merge.

Comment: When doing a pull request, will the commit history from feature1 get stored or ignored when merging to develop branch?

Comment: @variable As long as it is a simple merge (no squashing), the commit history of feature1 will be available as second parent of the merge commit representing the accepted pull request on develop.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer depends on how quickly things are merged into master branch. I am not a huge fan of feature branches because they can be difficult to merge into master if multiple teams are editing the same files for different feature branches.

The way we do branches in my company is we have:
`production` - the current version running in production
`master` - the release candidate is cut from this branch. It's experimental, but we should only merge "working" code. We should never knowingly break `master`.

And that's it. Our pull requests are against `master`. People can use feature branches, but you're responsible for the merge conflicts. Each pull request into `master` requires a JIRA ticket for compliance.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first option so everything is conflicted which will be resolved locally and then will push to master.